What are the pros and cons of this 3 gender/sex & pseudosexual reproduction system?
So I was revisiting this world I partially built a few years ago called Purpalis. In it I gave an Earthesque world some interesting modifications like the sky and water being purple, clouds being green, more seasons, and in terms of life, having 3 genders/sexes and 'pseudosexual' reproduction be the biological norm, for most animal life at least.
Basically instead of male and female, there is Inseminator/Babymaker which makes eggs and sperm/fertilized eggs, who then deposits them into the Incubator who holds them until they fully or mostly develop, who then finds a Caretaker/Babytaker to pass on the young to be raised by them. I call this pseudosexual reproduction as while it technically is asexual reproduction as only one sex makes gametes, the process of the Inseminator putting its load into the Incubator is sexualish.
My question is what are the realistic benefits and drawbacks of such a gender/sex and reproduction system?

if only one sex is produceing gametes then that is the only one reproducing meaning the others are suffering a huge detriment, really its a host parasite relationship. 3 sexes each contributing genetic material would be easier,

(1) The proposed reproduction system is asexual; the main drawbacks of asexual reproduction systems are reduced variability and increased vulnerability to genetic abnormalities; their main advantage is energetic efficiency. That's supposed to be well-known. (2) The eusocial insects, such as ants and bees, do have a three-gender system, with male drones, fertile female queens and sterile workers; among other duties, the sterile workers do take care of the larvae. That's also supposed to be well-known.

Adding that these facts are well known was unnecessary. I knew about the genetic diversity thing but figured there might be more than one negative and there could be positives. Also I am pretty sure workers are considered female, not a separate sex. @AlexP

Yes, the workers are genetically female. That's why I said three gender system.

Why is the third condition (caretaker/babytaker) considered part of the reproduction process? It's a nanny. At best a wet nurse. It's a cultural role, not a sexual role, not even deserving of an assignment of gender or sex - unless it's a sexless drone that does nothing but child rearing. Is it? Also, please narrow your question to the kind of benefits/detriments you're looking for. So long as "the third allows the other two to gamble at the local casino once child bearing is done" the question should be closed as needs more focus. Thanks.

Might be better to have the genders as 'phases' in each species life cycle i.e. all young are born asexual. Upon reaching puberty they enter a male phase. Once they mate post coitus hormonal changes make they phase to females. If they again mate and bear young? Post birth they phase back to males. This cycle repeats several times until after multiple phases they enter a stable 'menopausal' like phase as mature care givers. In this scenario puberty arrives earlier in the life cycle of a species & menopause does to. Most of the lifespan is spent in the caregiver phase.

Division of tasks and Potential Overdependecy .
That's mostly it, and it seems somewhat counterintuitive, but fully possible:
New Mexico Whiptail lizards are a species of lizards composed exclusively of females. They stand as an example that asexual reproduction with the presence of genetic diversity is technically possible in multicellular organisms. Your species would likely require similar processes to happen during gametogenesis to work (work = not risking everyone dying from a disease spreading or similar factors).
At the same time, seahorses show that its technically possible for the transfer of eggs, as in them the females introduce their eggs inside a special brood pouch in the male to be fertilized and develop until the babies are ready to be born. In your species however, they play no role in genetic diversity.
so based on the real world, your purpalis species would likely work very similarly to an ant colony: everyone has a very similar genetic makeup, but since only one of the three types of individuals contributes to genetic diversity this must mean every baby has the potential to become any of the three types of purpalis, with differences in how they're cared for and the type and amount of food they receive from the caretakers likely being what determines whether they'll grow to be inseminators, incubators or new caretakers.
Pros
The greatest upsides are that living together offers greater security and allows for division of labor and potentially specialization, allowing for specialized castes to appear under the right conditions, ensuring the species has different groups of individuals highly specialized to perform specific tasks. A similar version of this is seen in many eusocial insects, so its both possible and in many ways a clearly advantageous social structure for much the same reasons.
Cons
Meanwhile, the most glaring downside depends on just how specialized the purpalis are. The presence of an incubator when the inseminator is wholly responsible for egg cell production seems disadvantageous, but in practice their reproduction is very similar to most dioic species, so its far from somethng absurd or a crippling disadvantage. HOWEVER, you need to ask one question: can either of the two act as a temporary caretaker? If yes, then no issues, otherwise, your species becomes highly sensitive to most environmental changes, because in that case only one of the three types is required for egg cell production and genetic diversity, yet all three are necessary for successfully reproduction, except unlike with most animals, if anything causes even one of the three to die, the colony will die alongside them. Sure, in an established colony/community with multiple incubators, inseminators and caretakers this offers a much smaller risk, but it still means that any case of propagation of the species requires at least three individuals to leave the colony together and survive until they can all reach a new place to settle, otherwise even if only one dies, the remaining two will be unable to successfully raise new generations, their lineage doomed unless they somehow find another caretaker willing to fill the role (no inseminator or incubator? no new babies. No caretaker? make as many babies as you want, none of them will make it to adulthood).
Personally, I'd say this structure is not impossible by any menas, but it is unlikely, and there's a good chance it may fall apart in favor of a two-caste system rather than a three-caste one, let me tell you why:
Let's picture a scenario in which a mutation occurs: one individual in your species somehow develops into something in the middle of all three castes. They're meant to be an incubator, but unlike their fellow incubators it is fertile and has some caretaker traits to boot. This is a mutant not meant to exist and a very rare thing to happen in general, yet it takes only one fo these to successfully appear and establish a colony for the species to most likely change. I'll call it a triarch purpalis for simplicity.
Unlike other purpalis that need to leave their communities in groups of at least three to successfully establish themselves in a new region, the triarch can go alone. If it finds a suitable place, it will face an initial disadvantage of being alone, having to perform all three functions by itself in addition of having to leave to get food and water instead of having at least some help. That said, if it manages it, it'll have a whole new group of caretaker children ready to take over the function of caring for the young and providing for the colony as soon as they're fully developed, meaning the triarch  mother will then be able to worry exclusively about reproduction. At the same time, fertile triarchs can leave the colony alone, meaning you now have a situation where you can raise three fertile triarchs that will leave and found each their own colony, meanwhile the purpalis must always raise a triad of inseminator caretaker and incubator, all three having to stay together in order to found a single new colony or community. Even if triarchs don't leave alone, a simple pair of a fertile triarch and caretaker bodyguard would suffice and even result in a massive advantage compared to the purpalis, because while the purpalis need to ensure all three make it, the triarch pair only needs to ensure the fertile triarch makes it, as the caretakers survival only really means the triarch will have an easier time, but is in no way essential for it to establish a new colony.
Fun fact: that's exactly how many species of wasp and ant work, with flying queens previously fertilized by males leaving their colonies in large numbers to each found its own new colony, caring for the first batch of young until they mature, allowing the queen to assume her post as full-time baby factory while the workers take over the other tasks needed to maintain the colony.

exactly my thoughts. I find it hard to justify the existance of the babymaker as a separate gender. Both bearing a child and rearing a child are great efforts, take a lot of energy and can benefit a lot from a specialized body structure. Creating fertilized eggs doesn't need very big specialized organs so it would not be much detrimental to the other two (or one of them) to have this as well, but instead even adventagous like you laid out.

Conditionally, yes.
Condition: They are not different sexes, but different developmental phases of the same species.
One thing you'll see quite a bit in nature is organisms taking different roles at different ages; elephants becoming nursemaids after their breeding days are over, clownfish transitioning from male to female at a certain maturity (and size), sea-squirts starting life as free-swimming with a relatively complex nervous system - then bedding down on a rock or suchlike as their nervous system is largely reabsorbed as no-longer-needed.
My suggestion:
Stage 1): They grow to sexual maturity and produce a viable gamete. (Which they impregnate stage 3 with)
Stage 2): They care for young, running around after them and keep them safe - teaching them as appropriate.
Stage 3): They become relatively sessile and serve as incubators for new-bundles of cells to develop into offspring.
Ideally, I'd recommend that you add a recombinant phase at stage 1) whereby some genetic material can be added from another member of the species so that genetic coherence can be preserved within the species and that their immune-systems and they can evolve to combat depredations of the predators and microbes/parasites they'll encounter.
